# Salesforce SOSL: matching fields exactly

Tags: salesforce

Afternoon All.

I am using a simple SOSL query like this

```
find {"2099"} in phone fields
```

and it is returning objects that match 12320995, as an example. Is there a way to set up the query to only return exact matches?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm
Which has the example

> List> searchList = [FIND 'map*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (id, name), Contact, Opportunity, Lead];

In your case, specify the objects you want to return.
Specify the fields you want to search in.

Comment: Thanks for this Bryan. The problem is not that the wrong fields are being searched it's that the query is matching "\*<term>\*". What I want is to match "<term>". In this instance, I am trying to match all records that match 2099 (an internal telephone extension) and I don't want matches where 2099 is part of the number. I just want exact matches. Have I missed the point?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, "Use quotation marks around search terms to find an exact phrase match."

The " " operator should return exact matches. I haven't tested it but if it does not work it could be a bug. One suggestion is that you scan through the results with your own code and filter out the exact matches.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have experimented with quotes, and it doesn't appear to change the behaviour, except that you can include spaces. I still get a match in the above case (where the search phrase is present in the string being searched), and I only want exact matches.

Comment: It seems that the quotation marks {" "} can only be used to find exact phrase (collection of words and spaces) and not a single word.